# Am updating status of order to "activated" using trigger but its throwing error "System.FinalException: Record is read-only: Trigger.UpdateStatus: l"

Tags: trigger

```
trigger UpdateStatus on Order (after insert,after update) {
List<order> ord=[Select Id,Opportunity__c,AccountId,EffectiveDate,CurrencyIsoCode,Status,TotalAmount from Order];
{
for(Order o1 : Trigger.new){
if(o1.Opportunity__c!=NUll && o1.Status=='draft' && o1.TotalAmount!=null)
o1.Status='Activated';
}
}
}
```

If the code is wrong please tell me how to achieve this

Answer (score 6):

You cant update the same record after update or insert. You should do this in the before event i.e. change `after` to `before` in your code. After update/insert is typically for updating some other object record after successful update of this one.

Comment: Then how to achieve this one can give  some code am new to to development am trying to achieve this

Comment: Did you try to changing the trigger from after event to before, as mentioned in the answer?